# Is it normal for fiberglass to face down in basement?

Tags: electrical, insulation, framing

Image attached below. Entire basement has the fiberglass pointed downward and the paper touching the ceiling above. Why wouldn’t it be the opposite way so  the fiberglass isn’t just hanging down?

[image]

Comment: The paper is the vapor barrier. Though plenty of folks do it the other way, and then have soggy messes ripping their way out of the joist bays after a few years. Assuming you don't heat your basement (much) you could place some mesh or the like to hold it in place, and apparently also add some unfaced to where this is thin, unless it's just compressed and needs to be fluffed out. If you heat the basement similar to the floor above, it's not doing much anyway.

Comment: Wow, so this way is correct, huh?  Sounds like a simple job of getting some 1/2" plastic mesh "chicken wire" fencing material from the farm store,, and rolling it out and stapling it to the ceiling joists where appropriate.

Comment: Jeff, I noticed that you've asked quite a few questions but haven't resolved any of them. Please [take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you understand the process and be sure to reward your volunteer helpers appropriately. This also prevents effectively resolved questions from popping up in the review list.

Answer (score 2):

It's standard for paper to go on the warm-in-winter side. You can get mesh or spring steel rods to keep the fiberglass a little bit tamed, but encapsulating it entirely is a different matter.